# PHP creating a ping script need to convert response to object to read it

Tags: php

I'm creating a RCP ping script. 
The response I get when I ping looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>flerror</name>
                        <value>
                            <boolean>0</boolean>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>message</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>Thanks for the ping.</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I want to read the XML response and write the message to the user. However to do this I need to convert the response into a object (I think).

My script:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n",
    'content' => $xml
)));
$file = @file_get_contents("https://rpc.twingly.com/", false, $context);
if ($file === false) {
    echo '<p>Could not connect!</p>';
}
elseif ($file) {


    echo '<p>The following response was returned:</p>';
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($file).'</pre>';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($file->params->param->value->struct->member as $object){

        $name[$i]       = $object->name;
        $value[$i]      = $object->value;

        echo"
        <p>Name: $name[$i]<br />
        Name: $value[$i]</p>
        ";

        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Empty response!</p>';
}
```

My error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'params' of non-object in
>   C:\Users\usr\wamp64\www\fitnesslife\blog\my_blog_ping.php on line 556
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'param' of non-object in
>   C:\Users\usr\wamp64\www\fitnesslife\blog\my_blog_ping.php on line 556
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'value' of non-object in
>   C:\Users\usr\wamp64\www\fitnesslife\blog\my_blog_ping.php on line 556
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'struct' of non-object in
>   C:\Users\usr\wamp64\www\fitnesslife\blog\my_blog_ping.php on line 556
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'member' of non-object in
>   C:\Users\usr\wamp64\www\fitnesslife\blog\my_blog_ping.php on line 556
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\Users\usr\wamp64\www\fitnesslife\blog\my_blog_ping.php on line 556

Comment: There is a few ways to Read Write XML,  Such as XMLReader or SimpleXml or etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` returns a string, not an XML object.

You can convert it to an XML object with [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) like this:

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_string($file);
```

Another approach is to use the [`SimpleXMLElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) constructor while you get the contents:

```
$xmlfile = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("https://rpc.twingly.com/", false, $context));
```

Comment: Super, I used $response = simplexml_load_string($file);

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
print_r($xml);
```